# android JSON in ListFragment

Tags: android, json, android-listfragment

I'm new to android development. I've no problem with the JSON when used in the mainactivity but got problem when move the code to ListFragment

this line nothing happen:
JSONObject json = userFunctions.announcementFeed(myID, myType);

Here is the full code:

```
package com.example.demo123;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import library.UserFunctions;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class AnnouncementList extends ListFragment {
private static final String TAG = "MyAnnouncement"; 

JSONArray announcementList = null;            
UserFunctions userFunctions;

String myID = MainActivity.myID;
String myType = MainActivity.myType;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG,"START ANNOUNCEMENT LIST");

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> theAnnnouncement = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONObject json = userFunctions.announcementFeed(myID, myType);

    try {
        if (json.getString("success") != null) {
            announcementList = json.getJSONArray("announceDT");
            for (int i = 0; i < announcementList.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = announcementList.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = c.getString("topic");
                String course = c.getString("course") + " - " + c.getString("courseTitle");
                String created = "By " + c.getString("entered_by") + " | " + c.getString("entry_date");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("title", title);
                map.put("course", course);
                map.put("created", created);

                theAnnnouncement.add(map);
            }
        }                
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] from = { "title","course","created" };
    int[] to = { R.id.title,R.id.course,R.id.created};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), theAnnnouncement, R.layout.list_item, from, to);            
    setListAdapter(adapter);        
}
```

}

Comment: What is LogCat saying? What is your announcementFeed() function supposed to be doing? Any networking? A little more detail would help

Comment: @JadeByfield you can view the logcat here http://www.letmecode.com/tmp/log.txt

Comment: @JadeByfield for the announcementFeed() : http://www.letmecode.com/tmp/announcement.txt

Answer (score 1):

Why is it absolutely necessary to put that logic in onActivityCreated? Your Fragment will not be fully initialized at that point so you might want to move that logic to onResume or somewhere else.

EDIT: I took a look at the code you linked, as well as the announcementFeed() method.

It looks like you're trying to do some networking on the main thread, from this method;

```
public JSONObject announcementFeed(String username, String userType){
    ..................................

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}
```

You're calling this method in onActivityCreated. I suggest moving this to background thread or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Still, without the LogCat I can't be 100% sure what's happening, but at least we're able to point that out off top.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try the AsyncTask. Btw here is the logcat http://www.letmecode.com/tmp/log.txt